# Handling large word embedding matrix in Python

Tags: python, word-embeddings

I have a pre trained Glove word embedding matrix (U) of dimension (400000 * 50). Now for the purpose of query expansion I need to perform the operation matmul(U*U.T). This is the term by term similarity matrix. But this leads to a matrix size of (400000*400000) and Python is throwing me memoryError.

Is there a work around to this problem other than using a better machine ?

Comment: Maybe Matrix Factorization? If you Google you will find a lot about it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options. Here are several:

- Use NumPy, instead of pure Python. Make sure to compile NumPy with an optimized BLAS library.
- Use a framework like Dask to read only a part of the matrix at a time from disk.
- Choose a different method query expansion that does not require the inverse.
- Use the pseudoinverse.
- Choose a smaller embedding space.
- Reduce the precision of the numerical values.